# The "Previous" button is locked if any page except the last one is open

Tags: angular

In general, let's say you have a pagination with a  limit of 3 and with a step of 3. And at the moment you have 5 pages. Suppose we are on page 1, the “Previous” button is locked (this is how it should be), the “Next” button is working (everything is fine here too). But when we start to move to the next page using the "Next" button, the "Previous" button will still be locked until we reach the last page. But returning back to the penultimate page, the "Previous" button will be locked again. How to fix it?

ts:

```
  const STEP = 3
  const LIMIT = 3

  teams: Array<Teams>
  noMore = false
  limit = LIMIT
  offset = 0

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTeams()
  }


  private loadTeams() {
    const params = {
      limit: this.limit,
      offset: this.offset
    }
    this.teamsService.fetch(params).subscribe(
      teams => {
        this.teams = teams
        this.noMore = teams.length < STEP
      }
    )
  }

  Next() {
    this.offset += STEP
    this.loadTeams()
  }

  Previous() {
    this.offset -= STEP
    this.loadTeams()
  }
```

html:

```
  <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title"><b>Teams</b></span>
      </div>
      <div  class="collection">
        <div *ngFor="let team of teams" > 
          <a class="{{selected == team ? 'active' : ''}} collection-item" (click)="onSelected(team.team_id)">{{team.full_name}}
            <ng-container *ngIf="team.comment"><hr>Comment: <br> {{team.comment}}</ng-container></b>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <button class="btn-small waves-effect waves-light" (click)="Previous()" [disabled]="!noMore">Previous</button> 
      <button class="btn-small waves-effect waves-light" (click)="Next()" [disabled]="noMore">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current logic, the Previous button is only enabled when `noMore` is true - that is, on the last page. You don't want to use the same boolean variable for both the Previous and Next buttons, or they will never be enabled at the same time. Instead, try `[disabled]="offset <= 0"` for your Previous button. This will disable your Previous button on the first page, and the first page only.